Do you lose the right of attribution if you're charged with a crime?
Does anything in the Creative Commons license CC-BY-SA (4.0 or 3.0) allow the person you've licensed your content with to remove attribution because you're charged with a crime?
The specific case has no conviction yet.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

No
Why would you think it would?

There's nothing prohibiting a license from having a clause like this, is there? Obviously CC doesn't do so, but it presumably could.

This is why they asked the question.

Re stating that: "When someone is charged with a crime, they don't as far as I understand it, lose their rights under the Creative Commons license. I know one such user has had his right of attribution stripped. I find this action to be an overreach on StackExchange's part. He contributed to the network's success. His previous name on the network was "Luigi Mangione".
Was there a reason for deleting the desired name for attribution on this account? Or does StackExchange claim that they can strip attribution at any time when a person is charged, and not even convicted, of a crime?"

I was not aware that the license that Stack Exchange uses would prohibit changing a user's original chosen name. If that is the case, wouldn't the extremely common practice of anonymizing disruptive users violate that? Not that this seems to have aroused anyone's indignation, least of all the poster.... But for instance, if a user with username X starts spamming the site, they might have their account deleted and their name changed to "user12345", possibly leaving chat/comments/answers. Based on what you are saying here, it sounds as if that latter part is actually against the license terms?

@Obie2.0 worthy of a question of its own? Perhaps this is what the OP wanted to ask but didn’t.

The attribution is not a right of the grantor, nor a freestanding obligation on the grantee. Instead, it is a conditional obligation placed on the grantee.
One need not provide attribution. But if one does not, then one loses the associated conditional privileges and is at risk of a suit if one continues unpermitted use (e.g. for copyright infringement). It is open to persons / corporations to accept such risk. It is also open for them to stop sharing.
Under the CC licence, none of the above changes upon the grantor being charged with a crime.

Doesn’t this apply to just about everything? No one has to comply with laws etc if they are willing to face the risks of consequences. It seems like an overly literal interpretation of a question that hasn’t even been asked here.

@MisterMiyagi it's true that this answer addresses a question that wasn't asked explicitly, but its point is well taken in context.  Sometimes it's best to analyze legal matters in practical terms rather than simply considering in purely theoretical terms what is or isn't lawful.

@MisterMiyagi no this doesn't always apply. Sometimes someone does hold a right such that they can get a remedy forcing the other to comply. In this case, the licence does not give the grantor a right to attribution that can be enforced. Instead, it is the other than has a obligation, and even that obligation is conditional. This answer makes clear that licences don't typically create freestanding rights for the grantor.
